# kubelet stop post node status and node "k8sslave1" not found with kubelet in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

My local machine kubernetes cluster running fine yesterday util I install some component, my slave1 and slave2  only have 4G for each, and I check the free memory only have 100MB+, then I stop the VM and increase the KVM virtual machine memory to 8GB. And recheck the free memory to make sure it have 2GB+ free for each node. Now the slave1 and slave2 node not running fine,this is the node status:

```
[root@k8smaster ~]# kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME        STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION                CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8smaster   Ready      master   12d   v1.18.5   192.168.31.29   <none>        CentOS Linux 8 (Core)   4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64   docker://19.3.12
k8sslave1   NotReady   <none>   12d   v1.18.5   192.168.31.30   <none>        CentOS Linux 8 (Core)   4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64   docker://19.3.12
k8sslave2   NotReady   <none>   12d   v1.18.5   192.168.31.31   <none>        CentOS Linux 8 (Core)   4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64   docker://19.3.12
```

then I check one of the node status, it looks like this:

```
[root@k8smaster ~]# kubectl describe node k8sslave1
Name:               k8sslave1
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=k8sslave1
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4Address: 192.168.31.30/24
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4IPIPTunnelAddr: 10.11.157.64
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Mon, 13 Jul 2020 11:50:48 -0400
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  k8sslave1
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Sat, 25 Jul 2020 09:47:24 -0400
Conditions:
  Type                 Status    LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason              Message
  ----                 ------    -----------------                 ------------------                ------              -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False     Sat, 25 Jul 2020 00:48:55 -0400   Sat, 25 Jul 2020 00:48:55 -0400   CalicoIsUp          Calico is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       Unknown   Sat, 25 Jul 2020 09:43:45 -0400   Sat, 25 Jul 2020 09:48:07 -0400   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  DiskPressure         Unknown   Sat, 25 Jul 2020 09:43:45 -0400   Sat, 25 Jul 2020 09:48:07 -0400   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  PIDPressure          Unknown   Sat, 25 Jul 2020 09:43:45 -0400   Sat, 25 Jul 2020 09:48:07 -0400   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  Ready                Unknown   Sat, 25 Jul 2020 09:43:45 -0400   Sat, 25 Jul 2020 09:48:07 -0400   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.31.30
  Hostname:    k8sslave1
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  36702712Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             4311228Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  33825219324
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             4208828Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 0c9c1291618645498e63ddfe3895658a
  System UUID:                b25d27cf-4dea-44fe-96d8-a75e0c138187
  Boot ID:                    3290a714-0e18-47dd-a811-2dd16c8a17c9
  Kernel Version:             4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64
  OS Image:                   CentOS Linux 8 (Core)
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.12
  Kubelet Version:            v1.18.5
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.18.5
PodCIDR:                      10.11.1.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.11.1.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (16 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                                              CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                                              ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     apm-server-filebeat-dn48j                                         100m (5%)     1 (50%)     100Mi (2%)       200Mi (4%)     15h
  default                     traefik-88f7c94bf-tdz2m                                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         8d
  infrastructure              elasticsearch-elasticsearch-coordinating-only-7744945d6d-zwz7z    25m (1%)      0 (0%)      256Mi (6%)       0 (0%)         15h
  infrastructure              harbor-harbor-chartmuseum-575cdf84f6-2m5t5                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d14h
  infrastructure              harbor-harbor-clair-6464c85c99-zb997                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         35h
  infrastructure              harbor-harbor-notary-signer-5d9b779f54-fwzl8                      0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         36h
  infrastructure              harbor-harbor-portal-59c779dd74-lj5zl                             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d14h
  infrastructure              harbor-harbor-registry-6ffb84b667-cvxwq                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         3d14h
  infrastructure              harbor-harbor-trivy-0                                             200m (10%)    1 (50%)     512Mi (12%)      1Gi (24%)      36h
  infrastructure              jenkins-845bd5bcd4-4mkqn                                          50m (2%)      2 (100%)    256Mi (6%)       4Gi (99%)      4d14h
  kube-system                 calico-kube-controllers-75d555c48-wd84b                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         12d
  kube-system                 calico-node-2sj6v                                                 250m (12%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         12d
  kube-system                 coredns-676d976fcb-bxzcs                                          100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (1%)        170Mi (4%)     9d
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-f4lg4                                                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         12d
  monitoring                  prometheus-1595085197-node-exporter-ztgd4                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7d13h
  monitoring                  prometheus-1595085197-server-57967bb676-ksl2k                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         7d13h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests      Limits
  --------           --------      ------
  cpu                725m (36%)    4 (200%)
  memory             1194Mi (29%)  5490Mi (133%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)        0 (0%)
Events:              <none>
```

it tell me the kubelet not send status info, then I check the slave1 node kubelet status:

```
[root@k8sslave1 ~]# systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-07-26 00:30:45 EDT; 8min ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 7192 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 17 (limit: 49628)
   Memory: 41.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─7192 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --cgroup-driver=systemd --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image>

Jul 26 00:39:31 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:31.625224    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
Jul 26 00:39:31 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:31.725575    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
Jul 26 00:39:31 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:31.825956    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
Jul 26 00:39:31 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:31.929822    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
Jul 26 00:39:32 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:32.030028    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
Jul 26 00:39:32 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:32.130344    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
Jul 26 00:39:32 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:32.230562    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
Jul 26 00:39:32 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:32.330896    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
Jul 26 00:39:32 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:32.431111    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
Jul 26 00:39:32 k8sslave1 kubelet[7192]: E0726 00:39:32.531472    7192 kubelet.go:2267] node "k8sslave1" not found
```

the process running fine but give me tips:`node "k8sslave1" not found`. why give me this tips? what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using kubeadm? if you are using kubeadm;  you can follow the next steps:

1. Delete slaves nodes

   `kubecl delete node k8sslave1`
2. From the slaves' nodes, execute:

   `kubeadm reset`
3. Then you need to join the slaves' nodes to the cluster, in the master node execute:

   `token=$(kubeadm token generate)`

   `kubeadm token create $token --ttl 2h --print-join-command`
4. Paste the output of the command in the slaves nodes.

   `kubectl join ...`
5. Review that the nodes are join to the cluster and the new state is *Ready*.

   `ubuntu@kube-master:~$ kubectl get nodes`

   ```
   NAME            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
   kube-master     Ready    master   20d   v1.18.1
   kube-worker-1   Ready    <none>   20d   v1.18.1
   kube-worker-2   Ready    <none>   12m   v1.18.1
   ```

I hope it works for you. :)

Comment: I don't want to reinstall k8s slave node.I wish to find the reason and fix it.@jitapichab